# Read 2 data string

Tags: c, string

I have faced a problem with my program and I don't understand why. **I read 2 data string and the program just skips the first read and jumps on the second one.** I can't place the program here because is pretty big and I don't think anyone wants to waste time reading and understanding it.For example:

```
struct agenda {
    char nume[20];
    char prenume[20]; 
} vector[50];

void adaugare (){
    printf("x=");
    gets_s(vector[0].nume);
    printf("y=");
    gets_s(vector[0].prenume); 
}
```

And when I build and run it, it only reads the second string.Edit:

```
 struct agenda {
    char nume[20];
    char prenume[20];
}vector[50];

void adaugare();

void main() {
    adaugare();
    _getch();
}

void adaugare() {
    int numar;
    system("cls");
    printf("\n\tCate contacte doriti sa adaugati? ");
    scanf_s("%d", &numar);
    for (int i = 0; i < numar; i++) {
        printf("\nIntroduceti contactul %d\n", i);
        printf("\tIntroduceti numele contactului %d: ", i);
        gets_s(vector[i].nume);
        printf("\tIntroduceti prenumele contactului %d: ", i);
        gets_s(vector[i].prenume);
        }
}
```

So in this case if you build and run it, it only reads the second string.

Comment: I guess this is not the first input routine in your program...

Comment: See [ask], and then reduce the **relevant** portions of your code to a [mcve]. We can't help with code totally out of context.

Comment: Shouldn't the `gets_s` calls have a second parameter for the buffer size?

Comment: Since the problem is clearly in your `gets_s()` function, and you give us no code there, how are we supposed to guess what it does?

Comment: Ok I understand you need more information about the problem.I will simplify my program and I'm gonna post only the important part.

Comment: Simple rule of thumb when coding C: if you are a novice, avoid using `scanf`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you should elaborate what is gets_s() ? Is it your implementation of gets() or typo ? Instead of `gets_s` use `fgets()` to avoid buffering problem as mentioned in comments by  `@user3121023`

```
// gets_s(vector[0].nume);
  fgets(vector[0].nume,sizeof(vector[0].nume),stdin);
  printf("y=");
 // gets_s(vector[0].prenume); 
  fgets(vector[0].prenume,sizeof(vector[0].prenume),stdin);
```

EDIT(for visual c++) :

```
void adaugare() {
    int numar;
    system("cls");
    printf("\n\tCate contacte doriti sa adaugati? ");
    scanf_s("%d", &numar);

    fflush(stdin);
    for (int i = 0; i < numar; i++) {
        printf("\nIntroduceti contactul %d\n", i);
        printf("\tIntroduceti numele contactului %d: \n", i);
        fflush(stdin);
        gets_s(vector[i].nume);
        printf("\tIntroduceti prenumele contactului %d: \n", i);
        fflush(stdin);
        gets_s(vector[i].prenume);
        }
```

}

Because You must flush the input buffer(stdin) before using gets_s().

I hope it help's.

Comment: Can't use gets(), so I must use gets_s(). I tried with fgets same problem. You can copy paste my second code and replace gets_s with fgets and you will see it's the same problem.

Comment: I'm not sure about windows but it works fine  in  linux machine. Are you using visual c++  ? if yes then use gets_s(vector[0].name,sizeof(vector[0].name) ) and so on.

Comment: Yes, I'm using visual c++. I tried gets_s(vector[0].name,sizeof(vector[0].name) ) and it still doesnt work.

Comment: Then use fflush(stdin) before each gets_s() statement to clear stdin buffer.

Comment: I tried still doesn't work. And one more thing this 'bug' occurs only the first time, when variable i becomes 1,2,3,4 it reads both string's.

Comment: I edited my answer, run it, let me know if it still not works

Comment: I tried exactly as you said achal and it sitll jumps on the second one but only the first time as I said.Take a look : http://prntscr.com/hkxnw7 .

Comment: Nothing worked, so if anyone is still interested I avoided the '\n' from stdin stream like this : https://pastebin.com/U4rUTDmf . You were right @user3121023 and achal .